# How to get multiple data from server

Tags: php, css, mysql, algorithm, codeigniter

I have a CodeIgniter project which gets multiple data from server & display on webpage.

I wanna built something like [that](http://www.zeyneperdal.com/result1.jpg) for all items

I have 100+ multiple items stored in database. 
I wanna see first and second image when I enter website and then when I scroll page I wanna see third and fourth image and so on.

**My Model**:

```
public function getContent()
{
    $query=$this->db->get('my_database');
    return $query->result();
}
public function getCount(){
    return $this->db->count_all('my_database');
}
```

**My Controller**:

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->library('session'); 
    $this->load->model('My_Model');
}


public function index()
{
    $contents['content']=$this->My_Model->getContent();
    $contents['count']=$this->My_Model->getCount();
    $this->load->view('_header');
    $this->load->view('myview',$contents);
    $this->load->view('_footer');
}
```

**My View**:

```
       <?php       for ( $i=0 ; $i < $count/2 ; $i++ ){    ?>

        <div class="page-wrap">

    <?php    foreach($content as $cont){
      if ($cont->item_id %2 == 1): ?>

            <div class="item-left">
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="text-part">
                        <h2><?php  echo $cont->item_name ?></h2>
                        <p><?php echo $cont->item_text?></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="image-part">
                        <img src="<?=base_url() ?><?php
                        echo $cont->item_url?>" width="500" height="275" alt="" />
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>

       <?php else: ?>


           <div class="item-right">
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="text-part">
                        <h2><?php  echo $cont->item_name ?></h2>
                        <p><?php echo $cont->item_text?></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="image-part">
                        <img src="<?=base_url() ?><?php
                        echo $cont->item_url?>" width="500" height="275" alt="" />
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>           
<?php endif;     } ?>   
</div> <?php } ?>
```

Actually these codes working perfectly when I have only 2 items. 
But I have more than 100 items and my view is becoming [like that](http://www.zeyneperdal.com/result2.png)

I wanna continue left, right after left, right again. But my codes are working like left, left after right, right.

I really need your help. I've tried multiple if, for loops but I couldn't make it right. There is some logic error in my view php codes but I can't find it.

I wonder what if I can get 2 items from database instead of 1 image at same time. But I couldn't get only 2 image at same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Replace this:

```
   <?php else: ?>


       <div class="item-left">
            <a href="#">
                <div class="text-part">
                    <h2><?php  echo $cont->item_name ?></h2>
                    <p><?php echo $cont->item_text?></p>
                </div>
                <div class="image-part">
                    <img src="<?=base_url() ?><?php
                    echo $cont->item_url?>" width="500" height="275" alt="" />
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
```

with this:

```
       <?php else: ?>


       <div class="item-left">
            <a href="#">
               <div class="image-part">
                    <img src="<?=base_url() ?><?php
                    echo $cont->item_url?>" width="500" height="275" alt="" />
                </div>
                 <div class="text-part">
                    <h2><?php  echo $cont->item_name ?></h2>
                    <p><?php echo $cont->item_text?></p>
                </div>

            </a>
        </div>
```

**Updated Answer:**
Replace your posted **view** code with this:

```
<?php $first = false; ?>
<?php foreach($content as $cont): ?>


    <?php if ($cont->item_id % 2 == 1): ?>
        <div class="page-wrap">
            <div class="item-left">
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="text-part">
                        <h2><?php  echo $cont->item_name; ?></h2>
                        <p><?php echo $cont->item_text; ?></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="image-part">
                        <img src="<?php echo base_url() . $cont->item_url;?>" width="500" height="275" alt="" />
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>

        <?php $first = true;?>
   <?php else: ?>

            <div class="item-right">
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="image-part">
                        <img src="<?php echo base_url() . $cont->item_url;?>" width="500" height="275" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-part">
                        <h2><?php  echo $cont->item_name;  ?></h2>
                        <p><?php echo $cont->item_text; ?></p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>           

        </div>

        <?php $first = false;?>
    <?php endif; ?>   

<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php if($first): ?>
</div>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Hi Bluetree :) When I edited codes just like your said, display turned into normal thanks for that! But I saw only 2 first items everytime when I scroll page. I can't see 3rd 4th or 100th.

Comment: Do you want to display all items in one page only?

Comment: can you give me the count of this $content

Comment: Yes I wanna display all items in one page. I've created a mask which shows only 2 items until you scroll page. When I scroll page 1st and 2nd image goes away and we can see 3rd and fourth. Count is 100

Comment: Have you tried creating plain html just to test if your mask is working?

Comment: When I add,  <?php    foreach($content as $cont)  ?>   before 
   <div class="page-wrap">
I can see all items coming from database but this time every items duplicates. 
When I add "if block" after <div class="page-wrap"> I can't see even items. I can only see odd items. And the second part of view is becoming blank.

Comment: $count/2  what is this for?

Comment: You might think like that I've 100 items in my database but I wanna scroll 50 times to see all of them. inside  <div class="page-wrap"> I'm calling 2 database item. By the way I've tried to delete $count/2 loop and I got the same result :/

Comment: Please see my updated answer and test it if its working.

Comment: Thank you so much Bluetree for your effort! :) But with these codes I can't see two items in one page second one is ok but first one is empty

Comment: I see. I'll debug my code and get back to you. By the way have you tried to var_dump() your $content? just to confirm if there is really a 100 data

Comment: In your page-wrap there will be only two item? Am I correct?

Comment: And there will be 50 page-wrap